# Edit Png file text in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, png

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    },
  appbar:{
    background: "#3c3b63",
    text: "#ffffff",
    boxShadow: "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
   },
  toolbar:{
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    
  },
  icon:{
    display:'inline',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
    width:"75px",
    height:'75px'
   
  },
  
}));

export default function SearchAppBar() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="sticky" className={classes.appbar}>
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
          <img src = {icon} className ={classes.icon}/>
          
          <div className={classes.search}>
            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
            <SearchIcon />
            </div>
            <InputBase
              placeholder="Search…"
              classes={{
                root: classes.inputRoot,
                input: classes.inputInput,
              }}
              inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
            />
          </div>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**strong text**
I would like change the text in png file using reactJS.I want to see **US News** in single line.
FROM
[US
News][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1QPW.png
To
[US News][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VymgV.png

Comment: You can't change text in image. create new one

Comment: @Shubham Verma:Thank you.